# Reflection and Attributes in .Net Core refuse to cooperate

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have class:

```
    public class Domain
    {
        public static Assembly[] GetAssemblies()
        {
            var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
            foreach (ProcessModule module in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules)
            {
                try
                {
                     var assemblyName = AssemblyLoadContext.GetAssemblyName(module.FileName);
                     var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
                     assemblies.Add(assembly);
                }
                catch (BadImageFormatException)
                {
                    // ignore native modules
                }
            }

            return assemblies.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

My main class looks like:

```
class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<String, Type> animals;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assTab = Domain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (var assembly in assTab)
        {
            var m = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<Method>();
            if (m != null)
            {
                animals.Add(m.Name, assembly.GetType());
            }

        }
```

Where Method is a `MethodAttribute` class. In `Animal.dll` I have class like Dog, Cat etc. with Attribute `[Method("cat")]` and so on. To my dictionary I want to add this attribute name as string and type as Type `(dog, Dog)` and so on. My problem is that my program do not do that. After running program in variable animal I have 0 score. What should I change to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
var m = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<Method>();
```

This line is getting attributes on the assembly. So if the attribute is not applied to the assembly then you will get null back.

What you need to do is get the types in the assembly first and then check each type for whether it has the attribute on it. Something more like this:

```
foreach(Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    var attr = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<Method>();
    if (attr!=null)
    {
        animals.Add(attr.Name, type);
    }
}
```

Comment: but now do not see my dll. I set project animal as class library and in Main i add reference to it. But now my code fixed by yours execute in infinity :(

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean be executing in infinity? ie what line is it getting stuck on or if its a loop what is it looping over? My code only has a single foreach in it which shouldn't be able to get stuck... If you haven't already you should use the debugger to find out what is going wrong with it now. My guess is that it is somewhere later on that you are getting problems and that the fact you had nothing in your dictionary before is why you are only getting this issue now.

Comment: When I debug my code I see Animal in assembly table. In Animal I have class Dog which has attribute [Method('dog)]. But when I add your code and start debug it has see nothing like Animal just iterate through other assemblies

Comment: I'm a little confused... You say "I see Animal in assembly table" which I take to mean that you see that assembly in the response from `GetAssemblies`. But you then say "it has see nothing like Animal just iterate through other assemblies" which suggests that it isn't in the response from `GetAssemblies`...  My suggestions obviously haven't touched the getting assembly code, it just shows you how to loop through the types of an assembly. If it never reaches your animal assembly then I assume that it isn't in the loaded assemblies or something similar...